# Резервирование памяти в std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Хочу реализовать свой вектор для лучшего понимания работы данного контейнера. Можете объяснить за счет чего происходит "резервирование" памяти в векторе. Сомневаюсь, что там используют *malloc*, а потом при расширении контейнера *placement new*. Еще было предположение что просто инициализируется память конструктором по-умолчанию, а затем, снова таки, при расширении происходит обычное присваивание.

P. S. Очень тяжело читать исходники, так как я программирую только год

Comment: При резервировании памяти идет обращение к аллокатору вектора (который указывается как параметр шаблона), незанятое место в выделенном блоке никак особо не инициализируется, а при росте контейнера как раз вызывается placement new.

Comment: Вектор есть оболочка над обычным массивом. Массив в памяти хранится одним куском. При создании вектора он сразу резервирует место под массив из N элементов (метод capacity()). При добавлении количества элементов больше, чем N, вектор выделяет память под новый массив, размером N + N/2, копирует туда весь старый массив и новый элемент, после чего старый массив удаляется. Для выделения/удаления используются new[]/delete[].

Comment: @VTT понял, а есть какой то оператор или функция которая собственно и проводит аллокацию без инициализации?

Comment: Даже самый обычный `operator new` выделяет память без инициализации когда у типа создаваемых объектов тривиальный конструктор.

Comment: возможно, поможет: http://pcdev.ru/example-vector-part1/

Comment: зависит от реализации, в гнушной используется placement new[] в аллокаторе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже упоминалось в комментариях к вопросу, работа с памятью в векторе идёт через аллокатор, которым параметризирован шаблонный класс `std::vector`. Если он явно не указал, используется аллокатор по умолчанию. Никаких инициализаций конструктором по умолчанию не происходит, т.к. резервирование, а по сути функция `std::vector::reserve` не должна создавать объекты, её задача лишь подготовить плацдарм (память).

Когда вектор уже содержит какие-то объекты, резервирование при необходимости выполняет перемещение (вызывает перемещающий конструктор) существующих объектов в новую свежевыделенную память.